# How to make list item visible when it is behind padding of listview?

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-listview

I created a listview with 25dp padding

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:dividerHeight="25dp"
        android:padding="20dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"></ListView>
```

This is the look of the listview

[image]

When I scroll down the list, padding will over list item

[image]

Can I make list view visible range inside border of listview, not inside padding of listview?

---

List item xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="#fff">


    <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/button_history_list_item_one_function"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>


    <LinearLayout android:layout_width="100dp"
                  android:layout_height="match_parent"
                  android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@drawable/left_border"
        android:padding="10dp"
                  >

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

---

This image shows what I want

[image]

Comment: Remove `android:padding="20dp"`

Comment: can you put listitem xml?

Comment: If I remove the padding, there is no space at begin and end of the list, if not padding between listitem and listview, it is not look good

Comment: Try to set this : android:clipToPadding="false" properties to your ListView.

Comment: Yes, this is the accepted answer

Answer (score 0):

use margin instead of padding

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"></ListView>
```

Alternate way - If padding is important for you, use padding for left and right spacing inside listview and use margin for top & bottom.

```
<ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:divider="@null"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:paddingLeft="20dp"
        android:paddingRight="20dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"></ListView>
```